# Image scale causing memory overflow error

Tags: android, android-image

When I scale an image from a bitmap, the application gets shutdown.
So I saw the tab `LogCat`.
I found that the reason is memory overflow.
I didn't know how to release the memory, which is created by new.
Garbage collection does not work.

The code is as follows:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();

matrix.reset();

curScale += 0.02f;

h = orgImage.getHeight();

w = orgImage.getWidth();

matrix.postScale(curScale, curScale);

rtnBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(orgImage, 0, 0, w, h, matrix, true);

curImageView.setImageBitmap(rtnBitmap);

calculate(-0.02f);
```

Here the problem is `rtnBitmap`. As well as adding this, I even used the function `recycle()`. But it did not work.
I will wait your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you attempted to release the old object by setting all the variables that refer it to `null`?

Comment: How big is the image (bitmap, not compressed)?  Also, what device are you running on, and are there other things in your code that are taking up significant amounts of memory?

Comment: Thank you. How to release the old object? I know that java using garbage collection. So, there are no release functions. I used to image.recycle(), but the result is same. When scale down there are no errors. I used this in while loop. when the counter is over 3, the process is killed. Are there no more ways to using image.createbitmap() to scale image ? i use the because i'm a newer man for android.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rtnBitmap.recycle();` before using it if it is not NULL.

Comment: Thank you. I attempt to that. But It is same, When it running.

Comment: When it running. I use this in the "while". When the counter over 3, the process is killed. Are there the other ways to scale image. Not using Bitmap.createbitmap()?

Comment: Yes. I did. I use the code beginning of while loop. But there were no changes.